# Displaying Person Account's "Last Name" , "Salutation" and "First Name" fields on a Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, standardcontroller

In my org i have enabled Person Account, and i have a visualforce page where i need to get **Salutation,FirstName** and **LastName** field from person account, But when i call it using `<apex:inputField value="{!account.lastname}"/>` I'm getting only field label here i'm using "account" as a standard controller.

But I have used same line of code i.e `<apex:inputField value="{!account.lastname}"/>` to get contact's Lastname using "Contact" as standard controller

Here in the below code I'm getting only field label for "Salutation" and "Lastname" but I'm getting both label and field for "Account Name"

can anyone tell me what's problem here ?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="pick_list" >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >

   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
         <apex:outputlabel value="First Name"/>
         <apex:outputpanel >
         <apex:inputfield value="{!account.Salutation}" />
         &nbsp;
         <apex:inputfield value="{!account.FirstName}" />
         </apex:outputpanel>
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:inputfield value="{!account.lastname}"
  <apex:inputfield value="{!account.name}"
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

This is what i expected to come

[image]

But Here is the screen of what i'm getting

[image]

Kindly tell me what's wrong here 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941982/creating-salesforce-person-accounts-via-visualforce.I guess you will need to write an extension controller and use contact fields and render only when IsPerson is true .

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000095c8IAA.One from Developer forum to help you

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, you need to change your pageBlockSection to be of size 1 (it is 2 by default).

Is this for a 'new' Account?  Or existing one?  Are you 100% sure its already a personAccount if it is an existing one?

```
<apex:pageBlockSection >

   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem columns="1">
         <apex:outputlabel value="First Name"/>
         <apex:outputpanel >
         <apex:inputfield value="{!account.Salutation}" />
         &nbsp;
         <apex:inputfield value="{!account.FirstName}" />
         </apex:outputpanel>
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:inputfield value="{!account.lastname}"
  <apex:inputfield value="{!account.name}"
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting situation. For existing PersonAccounts, your page should display the FirstName and LastName fields as editable fields. But this is based on that account being tied to a PersonContactId. One thing to note here accessing Account.Name on a PersonAccount will cause an error.

For a brand new Account, IsPersonAccount is false and the field is not writable. One way to manage this would be to have a Contact in your extension class for the data entry. When you save, save the contact and associate it with the new Account, making it a PersonAccount. A bit of a process but hopefully someone has a better suggestion. 
One other thought that occurs to me is setting the record type of the account to be a PersonAccount in the extension and see if that works a little better.

Comment: Side question but can an org have normal accounts and personaccounts? Or does it have to be one or other. I am interested in the concept but new to the idea.

Comment: Yep - absolutely, @n34_panda. You can have both types of accounts in the same Org. PersonAccounts are enabled by Salesforce on request.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll ask for it to be set in a sandbox then I can take a look at the differences. We deal with individuals more than b2b so it could be useful. We are currently simply assigning contacts to generic accounts so they aren't private ... Lots to learn with salesforce